# bearer JWT token client authentication and access token issued by authorization server

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt

authorization server issues an access token with issuer details which are exposed in well-known api of that server. this server uses client authentication JWT token with clients configured , these JWT tokens are sent as a part of request from clients to authorization server and having one of the claim audience of authorization server with URL and port.

Now, the question is should well-known api have the same issuer URL(access token) details as audience in (JWT), or the JWT audience can be different URL with port of authorization server.

payload of client authentication JWT

```
{
"aud":"https://server:port"
}
```

payload of access token JWT

```
{
"iss":"https://server/address/abc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CLIENT ASSERTIONS**

The rules for using JWTs as client assertions are explained in [RFC7523](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523#section-2.2). This is different to JWT access tokens issued by the authorization server. A typical header and payload looks like this:

```json
{
  "kid": "1",
  "alg": "RS256"
}
{
  "sub": "my-client",
  "iss": "my-client",
  "aud": "urn:mycompany.com",
  "jti": "7eb87efb-2094-ecf0-531a-357c1d570582",
  "scope": "read",
  "iat": 1651070751703,
  "exp": 1651070811703
}
```

The client application has its own private key and uses a JWT library to issue the JWT. The corresponding public key used by the authorization server to verify client assertions can be pasted into the OAuth client registered in the authorization server.

Alternatively an external JWKS URI can be configured against the OAuth client. The party providing the client then provides the JWKS endpoint.

**ISSUER**

This must always the client application when using client assertions, as explained in section 3.1 of the above spec. In my example this is the value `my-client`.

**AUDIENCE**

The `aud` claim must represent the authorization server, as explained in point 3.3 of the above spec.

This can be the URL of the token endpoint, or the issuer URL or your issuer identifier, eg `urn:mycompany.com`.

The most cutting edge behaviour is described in the [FAPI 2.0 profile](https://openid.net/specs/fapi-2_0-baseline.html#name-requirements-for-authorizat), for higher security apps. Point 20 says that the issuer identifier should be accepted in the `aud` claim. This is a requirement in order for the authorization server to be considered FAPI 2.0 compliant - not all auth servers are.

**ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION**

This is the standards based way to do it:

1. In your app's code, set `iss` to a value representing your client application, as in my example.
2. In your app's code, set `aud` to the issuer identifier of the auth server.
3. In the auth server, register an OAuth client. Configure the public key for the keypair used to create the assertion there. Either by value (pasting it in) or hy reference (JWKS URI). If there is a setting for issuer, configure the value of the client, which is `my-client` in the above example.

So the behaviour you describe seems correct and expected. Test with invalid values, and ensure that you get a 401 error.

Comment: Thanks Gary for responding. Yes, this how the auth servers are configured. However, there is no mention that auth server issuer URI should match the client JWT aud claims.  which is the correct behavior , as these are two different services hosted on server. So, aud URI of client authentication JWT can be different from access token JWT issuer claim

Comment: The aud (array) claim must contain a value representing the auth server issuer. Point 3 of the spec I linked to clarifies this. Some providers may use the issuer URI, though the token endpoint is preferred, since this is where the JWT is sent.

Comment: Yes, the aud contains the value of auth server endpoint. but to say that auth server issuer endpoint match exactly with aud (basepath+URI+port) should not be the case

Comment: I added some info, since we were discussing this at work earlier. Is FAPI 2.0 what you are referring to???

Comment: FAPI 2.0 looks also similar to what i am asking. i have updated my comment above. There is no issue in identifying the aud by server. but the point was that , if you see above payloads. aud and iss values are different. and do not match exactly with each other. but server accept the client JWT and issue access token with iss.